# The PDF of $Y = X_1^2 +X_2^2 -2X_1X_2 \cos (\theta)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent random variables where they are not necessarily identical and greater than and $X1, X2 >0$. Here $X_1$ and $X_2$ undergo Nakagami-$m$ distribution.
Let
$$ Y^2 = X_1^2 + X_2^2 - 2\cos (\theta)X _1 X_2$$
where $\theta$ is nothing but a constant angle. I am seeking for the PDF of $Y$ or $Y^2$. I tried to derivate but my calculations did not go as well coordinated at all. Have you got any offer for me to derivate? Or is there a generic way to follow?

Comment: Your wording is confusing. Is the assumption that $X_1,\,X_2$ are independent variables that each have a [Nakagami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution)-$m$ distribution? Or are they each allowed a different value of $m$?

Comment: Yes, they can have different m values.

Comment: Different $\Omega$s too?

Comment: Yes different constituve parameters